# Creating GUI for Bantumi game

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

I've written backend for simple [Bantumi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala) game. Now I'd like to create a simple GUI for it, so that it would look like this :

[image]

How to start ? What layout should I use, and what type of component each element should be?
Classes :
[Basket](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/217568/)
[Player](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/217569/)
[Game](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/217570/)
[Main](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/217572/)
[Shared](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/217573/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the layout, I would suggest that you have an outer `JPanel` that used something like a BorderLayout. It would contain the two end baskets and in the cetner another `JPanel` that employs a `GridLayout` to hold all of the playing baskets.

As for the classes,  it looks like your `Main` class is superfluous - you can just put the `main` method in your `Game` class and call that.   The `Shared` class and the `Player` class do not need to be represented as GUI classes, so they can remain as is.  I would suggest that you have your `Basket` method extend `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent()` method to allow for custom painting of the beans.  You have a choice with `Game`, you could make it extend `JFrame` or have it contain a `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be online game you can look at JavaScript canvas or Flash. Of course you can also create Java applet that uses something like combination of Swing and Java 2d

Comment: Based on the tags, I assume Java is the requirement already...  I think the question is about which specific widgets to use.

Comment: Sometimes people don't realize that Java can be used on the back but the actual drawing can be done entirely on the client (this particular game can probably be done entirely in JS) I'm just trying to generate some ideas

Comment: Based on the homework tag, I'm guessing there's not going to be much flexibility allowed.